# How to match a word from array javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have javascript array.
i need to match and select words from this array.

```
var tomatch = "";

var sets= new Array()
     sets[0]='nnd';
     sets[1]='nndha';
     sets[2]='ch';
     sets[3]='gn';
```

as a example... 
when,

```
  var tomatch = "nn";
```

it need `tomatch` with `sets[0] & sets[1]` and
write out the result.

as when `tomatch = "c"`, it should match with `sets[2]`
how can i do this ?

there i dont need an oder.
if `tomatch = "dh"`, it can also be `sets[1]`

i have not good knowlage about javascript.

How to do this?

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript.

Comment: Use `for()` loop that uses `indexOf()`. Please show what you've tried, we're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: i know that Barmar, sorry i havent good knowlage about javascript. so..im tring to learn it by doing this. - im trying to build eazy typing method for a Language.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is there any relevance with Java here?

Comment: @RajeshPaul the question was tagged as Java.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

indexof("string to match") will return the index of the string or -1 if the string is not found. Simply loop through the array and check if the return value of indexof("string to match") is -1.

```
sets[i].indexOf("nn")!=-1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following function to return an array of matched words otherwise alert `no match`:

```
function find_match(to_match)
{
    match_array=new Array();
    for(i in sets)
    {
        if(sets[i].indexOf(to_match)!=-1)
            match_array.push(sets[i]);
    }
    return (match_array.length==0? alert('No match'): match_array);
}
```

To find match for say string `'n'` you need to call `find_match('n')` which will return `nnd,nndha,gn`

Comment: Why would you use inline script tags and document.write just to display the results?

Comment: @Todd just given for directions for use. Removed it. Now does it deserve a **downvote**? Did you find any other flaw?

Answer (score 0):

```
var tomatch = "nn";
var sets= new Array()
     sets[0]='nnd';
     sets[1]='nndha';
     sets[2]='ch';
     sets[3]='gn';    
for(var i=0; i < sets.length ; i++){
       if(sets[i].indexof(tomatch) !== -1){
         return sets[i];
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter:

```
> sets.filter(function(x) { return x.indexOf("nn") !== -1; })
[ 'nnd', 'nndha' ]
> sets.filter(function(x) { return x.indexOf("c") !== -1; })
[ 'ch' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
   function isInArray(string){
     return sets.indexOf(string)>-1;      
   }

   alert(isInArray("nn"));
```

OR with jQuery:

```
jQuery.inArray("nnd",sets);
```

it will return the index of "nnd"

Answer (score 0):

This is not as neat as @Nirk's solution (I always forget about Array.filter) but you can replace my test function with Array.filter per his answer:

```
function test(a, f) {
  var i = 0,
      result = [];

  for (i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    result.push(f(a[i]));
  }

  return result;
}

function txtMatch(s) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('' + s + '');
  return function(t) {
    return pattern.test(t);
  };
}

var sets= new Array()
sets[0]='nnd';
sets[1]='nndha';
sets[2]='ch';
sets[3]='gn';

var toMatchFirst = test(sets, txtMatch('nn'));
var toMatchSecond = test(sets, txtMatch('c'));

console.log(toMatchFirst.join(', '));
console.log(toMatchSecond.join(', '));
```

I just created a quick string match function and then loop through the array, testing each, and returning an array of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you, but this is the one i wanted to, i think match cmd is right for my task.

```
  var sugest = "";
  var matchkeyword = "nn";

  var sets= new Array()
    sets[0]='nnd';
    sets[1]='nndha';
    sets[2]='ch';
    sets[3]='gn';
    sets[4]='nch';
    sets[5]='fu';
    sets[6]='Nui';


for(var i=0; i < sets.length ; i++){    

        if(sets[i].match(matchkeyword) != null) {
                    sugest = sugest + "<br>" + sets[i];
        }
}

 y=document.getElementById("sugdiv");
 y.innerHTML = sugest;
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use document.write to return the results. If not used carefully, document.write can be destructive. Relying on it for DOM insertion isn't a good habit to get into. And such a brute force method is totally unnecessary for this.